# Can not start jhispster sample application

Tags: jhipster

I'm new in jhipster, I cloned the sample generated Angular 4 application :
https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2.git

I run the project with eclipse, but the application is not working in the browser !!!

I did't make any change in the source, this is my console :

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\HATIME\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: C:\Users\HATIME\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.3\lib\snakeyaml-1.13.jar
20:25:21.854 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
20:25:21.860 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
20:25:21.861 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/D:/Work/workspace/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/target/classes/]

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.7.RELEASE ::
:: http://www.jhipster.tech ::

2017-10-26 20:25:25.190  INFO 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App  : Starting JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App on HATIME-PC with PID 4916 (D:\Work\workspace\jhipster-sample-app-ng2\target\classes started by HATIME in D:\Work\workspace\jhipster-sample-app-ng2)
2017-10-26 20:25:25.192 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App  : Running with Spring Boot v1.5.7.RELEASE, Spring v4.3.11.RELEASE
2017-10-26 20:25:25.193  INFO 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App  : The following profiles are active: swagger,dev
2017-10-26 20:25:25.620 DEBUG 4916 --- [kground-preinit] org.jboss.logging                        : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider found via system property
2017-10-26 20:25:31.188 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.AsyncConfiguration   : Creating Async Task Executor
2017-10-26 20:25:32.757 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] class org.ehcache.core.Ehcache-users     : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.792 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.jhipster.sample.domain.User    : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.800 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.sample.domain.Authority      : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.805 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.s.domain.User.authorities    : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.811 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.sample.domain.BankAccount    : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.816 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.s.d.BankAccount.operations   : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.822 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.jhipster.sample.domain.Label   : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.831 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.s.domain.Label.operations    : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.836 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.sample.domain.Operation      : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:32.844 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.g.j.s.domain.Operation.labels    : Initialize successful.
2017-10-26 20:25:33.326 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Registering JVM gauges
2017-10-26 20:25:33.360 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Monitoring the datasource
2017-10-26 20:25:33.361 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.config.MetricsConfiguration      : Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
2017-10-26 20:25:35.101 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Registering CORS filter
2017-10-26 20:25:35.421  INFO 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Web application configuration, using profiles: swagger
2017-10-26 20:25:35.422 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Initializing Metrics registries
2017-10-26 20:25:35.428 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Registering Metrics Filter
2017-10-26 20:25:35.429 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Registering Metrics Servlet
2017-10-26 20:25:35.435 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Initialize H2 console
2017-10-26 20:25:35.436  INFO 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.sample.config.WebConfigurer        : Web application fully configured
2017-10-26 20:25:36.046 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.config.DatabaseConfiguration     : Configuring Liquibase
2017-10-26 20:25:36.071  WARN 4916 --- [ng-2-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2017-10-26 20:25:38.669 DEBUG 4916 --- [ng-2-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase has updated your database in 2596 ms
2017-10-26 20:25:51.678 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2017-10-26 20:25:51.690 DEBUG 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 12 ms
2017-10-26 20:25:54.999  INFO 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App  : Started JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App in 33.101 seconds (JVM running for 34.175)
2017-10-26 20:25:55.000  INFO 4916 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.s.JhipsterSampleApplicationNg2App  : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'jhipsterSampleApplicationNG2' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://*.*.*.*:8080
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you launch yarn install to get the node_modules folder, and compile the front ?

Try:

- yarn install
- yarn run webpack:build
- yarn start

Comment: The second command "yarn run webpack:build" is not found !
yarn run v1.0.2
error Command "wepback:build" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: sorry, I was writing with my phone. It's yarn run webpack:build -> it's in the package.json file

Comment: I get an memory allocation exception :

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory